# Inserting character ( _ or : ) into string after it has been set

Tags: string, insert, fortran, character, fortran90

I am stuck on something probably really simple but I just can't figure it out. Simplified this is my Fortran code:

```
character(8)  :: date
character(6)  :: codetime
call date_and_time(date,codetime)
call system('mkdir ' //date//codetime)
```

It calls the system date and time and creates a folder with it. The result of this is a folder called `20150630094352`. This isn't that clear so I want to change it to `2015_06_30_09:43:52`. But I just can't figure out how to add the `'_'` and `':'` inside the already specified string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add it into the string, print substrings with the characters in between.

```
call system('mkdir ' //date(1:4)//'_'//date(5:6)//'_'//date(7:8)//'_'// &
            codetime(1:2)//':'//codetime(3:4)//':'//codetime(5:6))
```